# JSF 2.0 + Spring 3, retrieving request parameter via annotation

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2

In native JSF 2.0 environment user is able to refer to request parameters with something like

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.id}")
private Long id;
```

However I'm using Spring to manage JSF beans, so  *@ManagedProperty* annotation is ignored in my case. It's still possible to use *#{param.id}* statement in faces-config.xml, but annotation-based configuration is obviously much more preferable.

Is there any way to resolve such statements with Spring annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `@Value` with Spring Expression Language. There should be `request` variable available:

```
@Value("#{request.getParameter('id')}")
private Long id
```

Comment: I get this error: Property or field 'request' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?

Comment: @Nab Probably your context is not a WebApplicationContext or your bean is not request scoped.

Comment: That's strange, I am using a custom ViewScoped bean (http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=702). Spring is also implemented using Spring Boot with the main class extending a SpringBootServletInitializer. Calling the FacesContext's getRequestParameterMap works perfectly.